# Finding the suitable semantic search engine tool for querying an excel/csv file containing data rich in numbers

Tags: nlp, aws, azure-ml, search-engine

I have an excel dataset that has the columns: name of the test, user name, data source, total number of records, number of failed records, number of passed records, date of test execution etc. I want questions like the following to be answered: How many tests were executed by user_1?, What data source has the most number of failed records? How many tests were run on a particular date? etc.

I want to build a semantic search engine using which the user can get answers to the above questions. I tried Amazon Kendra which is an enterprise semantic search engine, but it didn't prove to be effective on numerical data analysis.

Now, I'm considering trying Azure Cognitive Search for the above use case.

Can someone please shed light on the right tool or right approach for my use case?